# How do I remove ScriptObjectMirror(jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror) since it is Deprecated?

Tags: java, spring, binding, nashorn, scriptengine

I have recently started working on this new project where we are decoding our message using **ScriptEngine** & **ScriptEngineManager**. Here we have used ScriptObjectMirror which is deprecated from JDK 11 (I believe) and now I am looking for another approach for this. Basically I want to remove nashorn API from my project.
Below is my method which I am using right now , I read it can be acheived using binding. Can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;

public ScriptObjectMirror DecodeString (String decodeString){
        File resource = new ClassPathResource("script/decode.js").getFile();
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        engine.eval(new String(Files.readAllBytes(resource.toPath())));
        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
        ScriptObjectMirror data = (ScriptObjectMirror) 
        inv.invokeFunction("DecodeElsysPayload", inv.invokeFunction("hexToBytes", decodeString));
        System.out.println(data.entrySet().toString());
        System.out.println("temperature:"+data.get("temperature"));
        System.out.println("humidity:"+data.get("humidity"));
        
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommendation with Nashorn depracated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827083/recommendation-with-nashorn-depracated)

Comment: I am only using ScriptObjectMirror from Nashorn API. So , sorry but that does not answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replaced it with Bindings

`bindings = (Bindings) inv.invokeFunction("DecodeElsysPayload", inv.invokeFunction("hexToBytes", encodeString));`